Show that on any nonempty set $X$ there always exist topologies, at least two, provided $X$ has more than one element.
Show that on any nonempty set $X$ there always exist topologies, at least two, provided $X$ has more than one element.
I tried solving this problem as follows:
First, I considered a discrete metric $d$ on $X$, i.e $d:X^2\to\Bbb R$ such that $d(x,y)=0,$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1,$ if $x\neq y.$
Now, if U is a nonempty subset of $X$ then, if $x\in U,$ we always fix, $r=1$, so that, $B(x,r)=\{y\in U: d(x,y)<r=1\}=\{x\}\subseteq U.$ This means, $U$ is open.
Thus, we may say that any subset of $X$ is an open set if the metric is discrete. Hence, the topology on $X$ induced by $d$ is given by the set $T=\{$ the set of all subsets of $X$ $\}.$
But I don't understand what other metric/distance function, should I consider on $X$ so that I get a different topology $T'$ (induced by this new metric) such that $T=T'.$ Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Do you know about the indiscrete topology?

You weren't asked for metric topologies.  Easier to just think about general topologies.

@BenSteffan No, what's that?

@ThomasFinley It's the topology with the fewest possible open sets, i.e. the one described in José Carlos Santos' answer.

@BenSteffan Oh, I see. But if $X$ and $\emptyset $ are the only open sets of $X$ then, shouldn't $X$ have atmost one element? But I the $X$ with which I am working in here, has more than one element as mentioned.

@ThomasFinley No, not sure why you would think that. You can make this definition on any set. Perhaps you should review the definition of "topology." :)

@ThomasFinley: Are you aware of the definition of a topology? You seem to be assuming that a topology is the collection of open sets of some metric space. That’s not the definition. (There is a connection between what “open” means in the metric space context and the topological context, but I wouldn’t focus on that until I had properly internalised the definition of a topology.)

Some sets have only one topology of a metric space. Those are finite sets.

@Joe I get it. Let X be a nonempty set(, not necessarily a metric space. Just any set). Assume that we are given a collection of subsets of X(, i.e any subset of $X$ maybe in that collection) say, $T$ satisfying (i)$ \emptyset, X\in  T.$
(ii) Arbitrary union of members of T again lies in T
(iii) The intersection of any finite number of members of T lies again
in T. Then, $T$ is called a topology on X. Am I correct?

@ThomasFinley: Yes, that’s the definition. (Although there is no reason to assume that X is nonempty. The empty set, together with its unique topology, is called the empty space.)

@Joe Ok, that solves my confusion. Thanks a lot!

Now, if (X,d) is a metric space, and T is the collection of sets which are open in X in the metric sense, then T is a topology on X, i.e. (X,T) is a topological space.) That’s the connection between metric spaces and topological spaces.

On the other hand, if (X,T) is a topological space, then T does not necessarily “come from” a metric. More precisely, there might not exist a metric d on X such that the sets which are open in (X,d) coincide with the sets in T.

You can take the topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$. If $a\in X$, then $\{a\}$ is not an open subset of $X$, with respect to $\tau$. Therefore, $\tau$ is distinct from the discrete topology.
On the other hand, note that if $X$ is finite, then every metric in $X$ induces the discrete topology. Therefore (again, when $X$ is finite) if you want a non-discrete topology, you will have to use a topology which is not induced by a metric.

If $X$ and $\emptyset $ are the only open sets of $X$ then, shouldn't $X$ have atmost one element? But I the $X$ with which I am working in here, has more than one element as mentioned.

No, if $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only open subsets $X$, $X$ doesn't have to have at most one element. The set ${\emptyset,X}$ is always a topology on $X$, according to the definition of topology. It's the so-called trivial topology (or indiscrete topology).

Let X be a nonempty set(, not necessarily a metric space. Just any set). Assume that we are given a collection of subsets of X(, i.e any subset of $X$ maybe in that collection) say, $T$ satisfying (i)$ \emptyset, X\in  T.$
(ii) Arbitrary union of members of T again lies in T
(iii) The intersection of any finite number of members of T lies again
in T. Then, $T$ is called a topology on X. This is the definition of a topology of an arbitrary set. Am I correct?

Yes, you are correct.

Thanks a ton! +1 from me. That solves my confusion.
